# DLL load failed for pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When I choose to run the code, I get an error message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MarkKenny/Desktop/GamTut.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pygame, sys
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."
>>>
```

I'm using Python 3.3.4 64bit and using the latest available version of Pygame.

All suggestions/answers would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the 64-bit version of Pygame? You say that you are using 64-bit Python, but you don't state which version of Pygame you are using other than "the latest available version".

Try typing the following into a python shell:

```
import pygame
```

If there is no result, pygame is probably installed correctly.
If this error appears, then you have not installed the correct version of pygame for your OS:

```
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

There are some unofficial 64-bit pygame binaries here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame I'm not sure how good they are because I don't have any experience with them, I just use the standard 32-bit version of pygame available here: http://pygame.org/download.shtml